# Tag merge request: [jasper] and [jasper-reports], [jasper] and [jasper-jsp-engine]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

**[jasper](/questions/tagged/jasper)  X 54**
**[jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) X 729**

There is many questions only tagged with [jasper](/questions/tagged/jasper) is actually related to [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports). I have been retagged >15 such questions.

- [JasperReports servlet dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586854/jasper-servlet-dependencies)
- [Group Header does not start on a new page even when 'Start on a new page' is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410560/jasper-reports-group-header-does-not-start-on-a-new-page-even-when-start-on-a)
- [iReport variable incrementor usage with list component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479256/ireport-variable-incrementor-usage-with-list-component)

And some questions should retagged to `not-exist` [jasper-jsp-engine](/questions/tagged/jasper-jsp-engine) ([Tomcat's JSP Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Jasper))

- [Change the class loader of the JSP servlet (Jasper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501035/change-the-class-loader-of-the-jsp-servlet-jasper)
- [Compiling JSP Files in a VFS in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511863/compiling-jsp-files-in-a-vfs-in-google-app-engine)

The [jasper](/questions/tagged/jasper) should eliminate.